# Como efetuar um POST utilizando a classe HttpUrlConnection do Android?

Tags: android, json, restful

Preciso enviar um `JSON` gerado na aplicação `Android` para uma aplicação Web.
Utilizando a classe `HttpUrlConnection` fiz a seguinte codificação:

```
private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ao executar, o sistema manda corretamente a URL do método e o `JSON`, só que a aplicação Web não recebe nada.
Utilizando o plugin `RESTClient` do Firefox fiz um teste, coloquei a mesma URL e o `JSON` gerado. Ao executar o método `POST` o registro foi incluído corretamente.

Por quê a aplicação `Android` não está enviando a solicitação corretamente?

Comment: Veja esse artigo, talvez possa te ajudar: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)

Comment: é, eu segui as indicações do post comentado, mas mesmo assim não está executando o método post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL obj = new URL(url);

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  //abre conexao

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); //fala que quer um post

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json"); //fala o que vai mandar

    connection.setDoOutput(true); //fala que voce vai enviar algo


    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    printStream.println(json); //seta o que voce vai enviar

    connection.connect(); //envia para o servidor

    String jsonDeResposta = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()).next(); //pega resposta
```

É muito importante trazer a resposta nessa classe, caso contrario voce não consegue enviar

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!